# How to JOIN tables using a range of dates without having procedures

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables, lets call them table A & B :-

Table A looks like this:

```
   A.Num1       |   A.Num2      |   A.Date      
   12345        |   38170       |   28/05/2013      
   12345        |   38170       |   29/05/2013      
   12345        |   38170       |   31/05/2013      
   12345        |   38170       |   01/06/2013      
   12345        |   38170       |   03/06/2013      
   12345        |   38170       |   04/06/2013  
   12345        |   38170       |   04/06/2013          
   12345        |   38170       |   07/06/2013
```

Table 2 (B) looks like this:

```
    B.Num1      |   B.Num2      |   B.Status    |   B.Date
    12345       |   38170       |   New         |   28/05/2013  
    12345       |   38170       |   Closed      |   31/05/2013  
    12345       |   38170       |   Reopened    |   04/06/2013
```

I need an table like this as output - It should basically contain all rows from table A + status from table B

```
    Num1        |   Num2        |   Status      |   Date
    12345       |   38170       |   New         |   28/05/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   New         |   29/05/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   Closed      |   31/05/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   Closed      |   01/06/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   Closed      |   03/06/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   Reopened    |   04/06/2013  
    12345       |   38170       |   Reopened    |   04/06/2013      
    12345       |   38170       |   Reopened    |   07/06/2013
```

Also, preferably through a simple SQL statement, rather than procedures.

Thanks in advance. Kindly comment for any clarifications

Indru

### UPDATE

When two rows in Table B have the status changed but on the same date, I am getting inconsistent values in the join.

Take an example:

I have two tables, say A & B. They are pretty large tables and they document a certain information. Table A documents by scanning the data every few days but lacks a status column
If there is a change, then table B gets a new entry with status column.
I need to match these two and derive a status for each entry in table A corresponding to B.

#### Table B

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
100 | 12345 | 38170 | 28/05/2013  | New
150 | 12345 | 38170 | 28/05/2013  | Closed
200 | 12345 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
250 | 12345 | 38170 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

#### Table A

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn
55  | 12345 | 38170 | 28/05/2013
99  | 12345 | 38170 | 30/05/2013
145 | 12345 | 38170 | 31/05/2013
192 | 12345 | 38170 | 31/05/2013
223 | 12345 | 38170 | 04/06/2013
```

#### Desired Output

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
55  | 11552 | 38170 | 28/05/2013  | New
99  | 11552 | 38170 | 30/05/2013  | Closed
145 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
192 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
223 | 11552 | 38170 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

Instead, I am getting: (using Jeffrey Kamp's reply)

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
55  | 11552 | 38170 | 28/05/2013  | Closed
99  | 11552 | 38170 | 30/05/2013  | Closed
145 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
192 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
223 | 11552 | 38170 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

And this: (using reply 2 - Mark Bannister)

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
55  | 11552 | 38170 | 28/05/2013  | New
99  | 11552 | 38170 | 30/05/2013  | New
145 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
192 | 11552 | 38170 | 31/05/2013  | Reopened
223 | 11552 | 38170 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

Clearly the record Id-55 can be either New or Closed since there are two entries on the same day (28/05/13) in table B. But logic is that it goes from New -> Closed -> Reopened
So is there any way of doing this?

Comment: But, considering your desired output, how can you logically associated at status value of 'New' with teh date '29/05/2013'?

Comment: I would consider a different design as joining on date ranges would cause poor performance

Comment: Kindly do not venture into the semantics of the table. I can assure you that this is the desired input & output!

Comment: Agreed, but I am stuck. This system is already implemented. Changing the schema now is not an option...

Comment: Are new, closed, and reopened the only statuses possible?

Comment: Nope, there are 2 more. And more may be added. But the second table B is the master of sort. The status changes are logged & all entries in table A between the current status and the previously logged status have the same status - If you get what I am trying to say

Comment: i.e. All entries in table A on or after 28/05/2013 and before 31/05/13 will have the status new. And so on

Comment: not an answer, but a comment- this is a classic example of misusing normalisation. in order to log status changes about an entry, the initial design could have been better off if this is captured in one table.

Comment: @Krishna, not sure that this is a normalisation issue per se. Normally I'd solve this by storing a gapless date range in the history table, which would allow queries to find the current row easily.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - I believe they tried to address redundancy of the status values. that (level) for me is not required. when you say you are storing a gapless date range, that is also not an ideal way. status changes can be logged in one table. for e.g. if an entry doesnt change in status for 365 days, there is no need to physically store 365 records for that entry

Comment: I wasn't talking about 365 records, merely adding a redundant date column, so that the history table has a "From" and a "To" date for each status change. It means each status change needs to do an Update followed by an Insert, but it makes queries much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something simplistic for starters:

```
SELECT A.Num1
      ,A.Num2
      ,NVL(
         (SELECT DISTINCT
                 FIRST_VALUE(B.Status)
                 OVER (ORDER BY B.Date DESC)
          FROM   B
          WHERE  B.Num1 = A.Num1
          AND    B.Num2 = A.Num2
          AND    B.Date <= A.Date
         ),'New') AS Status
      ,A.Date
FROM A;
```

There's probably a better method that may work faster though.

Comment: This approach is simplistic and probably only suitable if you're only interested in one record at a time - but for reports you should use Bannister's approach.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select a.Num1, a.Num2, a."Date", b.Status
from TableA a
join (select TableB.*, 
             lead("Date",1) over (partition by Num1, Num2 
                                  order by "Date") NextDate
      from TableB) b
  on a.Num1 = b.Num1 and 
     a.Num2 = b.Num2 and 
     a."Date" >= b."Date" and 
     a."Date" < coalesce(b.NextDate,a."Date"+1)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e7cf/3).

Comment: It works, as per your link. But I am unsure as to whether this is Oracle SQL syntax. I am getting an error 'Invalid SQL statement'

Comment: Also why is Date in quotations?

Comment: @rtindru: Which version of Oracle are you using? If you look at the top left hand corner of the link, you should see that this is running in Oracle 11g; it's **definitely** valid in Oracle 11. (I think it should be valid in Oracle 10, and in any version of Oracle where Jeffrey's method works.) If you can include the full details of your error message, it might be possible to establish the cause. "Date" is in quotes because `date` is a reserved word in Oracle - I hope the actual column names in your database aren't reserved words.

Comment: Ah, okay, well the column name is not Date. I just shortened it. Will check again and get back to you. I think its Oracle 11.

Comment: It does work, and is a lot faster. But there are some rows in Table A that don't make it to the final output.

Comment: @rtindru: Can you include some sample data? The data supplied all seem to be picked up in the SQLFiddle.

Comment: It is an inconsistency with our database I guess. The query works on smaller samples, but fails on the whole table. Trying to get to the bottom of it. Thanks again

Comment: +1 This is a good approach and I suspect better performing than mine. The "b" subquery basically adds a "To" date so that each row represents a date range. If it's failing for some records you need to isolate them and perhaps run the subquery for them to see what's going wrong.