# How to select rows over a date range, with co-inciding dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have two tables, say A & B. They are pretty large tables and they document a certain information. Table A documents by scanning the data every few days but lacks a status column

Note: I need a query that does not explicitly mention the dates below - it needs to work on all such date ranges.

If there is a change, then table B gets a new entry with status column.
I need to match these two and derive a status for each entry in table A corresponding to B.

#### Table A

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
100 | 11552 | 82023 | 28/05/2013  | New
150 | 11552 | 82023 | 28/05/2013  | Closed
200 | 11552 | 82023 | 31/05/2013  | Standby
250 | 11552 | 82023 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

#### Table B

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn
55  | 11552 | 82023 | 28/05/2013
99  | 11552 | 82023 | 30/05/2013
145 | 11552 | 82023 | 31/05/2013
192 | 11552 | 82023 | 31/05/2013
223 | 11552 | 82023 | 04/06/2013
```

#### Desired Output

```
Id  | Num1  | Num2  | CreatedOn   | Status
55  | 11552 | 82023 | 28/05/2013  | New
99  | 11552 | 82023 | 30/05/2013  | Closed
145 | 11552 | 82023 | 31/05/2013  | Standby
192 | 11552 | 82023 | 31/05/2013  | Standby
223 | 11552 | 82023 | 04/06/2013  | Closed
```

Kindly suggest Oracle SQL queries for this selection.

If possible, efficient ones since the tables hava >100,000 records

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question: [How to JOIN tables using a range of dates without having procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059188/how-to-join-tables-using-a-range-of-dates-without-having-procedures)

Comment: @Mark Yes, the reason being that I faced another issue with the reply I got.
In the case when the table B has the status changed from New to Closed on the same date, my output showed Closed on both instances. It was hard to explain, so I put it up as a new question.

Comment: @Mat From table A. Basically, on the date-range of sorts. It has to check for every row in table B, the corresponding Table A status based on ID & CreatedOn

Comment: Is there a time part on CreatedOn? If not, why should Id 55 have status New, rather than Closed?

Comment: @Mark Exactly my problem. Well there is supposed to be a time component. Someone while fetching the data botched that up. And there is no explicit reason for it to be open. Implicitly though, any status starts goes like this New -> Closed -> Reopened.

Comment: *"Well there is supposed to be a time component. Someone while fetching the data botched that up."* Do you mean that there is a time component in the database, but it wasn't returned by the query - so Id 55 was created at the same time or after the New status, but before the Closed status?

Comment: @Mark no. This data is retrieved from a source where the extraction has been implemented poorly - thereby all time components are set to 00:00:0000 which renders them useless. And I know the obvious answer is to edit that - but I don't have that liberty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32079/discussion-between-mark-bannister-and-rtindru)